# Javascript regex replace function

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have the following string:

```
var str = "Test.aspx?ID=11&clicked=false+5+3";
str = str.replace(????????, 'true');
```

How can I replace the substring "false+5+3" with "true" using REGEX?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/clicked=[^&]*/, 'clicked=true');
```

this will replace anything in clicked parameter, not only false+...

Answer (score 4):

```
str = str.replace(/false\+5\+3/, 'true');
```

You need to escape the `+` since it means something special in regex.

Comment: my problem is that 5 and 3 are set dynamically... so I actually need to replace the substring that starts from "false" and till the end of the string...

Comment: `str = str.substring( 0, str.indexOf( "false" )+5 );`

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "Test.aspx?ID=11&clicked=false+5+3";
str = str.replace(/false[+]5[+]3/, 'true');
```